# Simplifying $\frac{4}{21}-\frac{8}{45}$ to $\frac{60-56}{315}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just came across this step, but I don't understand; please explain it to me.

$$\frac{4}{21}-\frac{8}{45}\quad\to\quad  \frac{60-56}{315}$$

Comment: What is the common denominator?

Answer (score 0):

To add or subtract fractions with different denominators, express them with the least common denominator.  (You can multiply the numerator and the denominator of a fraction by the same quantity without changing the value of the fraction, since $\dfrac m m=1$.)

The least common denominator for $21=3\times7$ and $45=3^2\times5$ is $3^2\times5\times7=315$.

$\dfrac4{21}-\dfrac8{45}=\dfrac{4\times15}{21\times15}-\dfrac{8\times7}{45\times7}=\dfrac{60}{315}-\dfrac{56}{315}=\dfrac{60-56}{315}=\dfrac4{315}$.